# Modal cannot be closed, Firefox says ReferenceError: event is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, modal-dialog, popup, referenceerror

What's wrong in this code that it works for all the browsers but not for Firefox? When a modal is triggered, it cannot be closed any more. It says "ReferenceError: event is not defined". see here: [Plunker snippet](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dovf6cjgprJ4dWjLpezm)

The relevant line (261) where the error occurs is this:

```
function dismissModal() {
  bindEvents(_dismiss, function(that) {
  hideModal(event);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Come on, where do you see `event` defined? The error is telling you exactly that: you are using `event` but it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: js noob here, sorry... can you please elaborate if you find it's not a waste of time for you. thanks....and why does it then work for all but Firefox

Comment: @0xc14m1z why so rude? `event` is global in other browsers @jennab see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036705/7404943)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't meant to be rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your Plunker.

The error is self explaining: event is being used before it has been defined, that's why you get the ReferenceError, because the scope manager is getting mad.

Your `dismissModal` method calls `bindEvents` passing two parameters, the second one seems a callback.

This is confirmed by looking at your Plunker at the definition of `bindEvents`, which is:

```
function bindEvents(el, callback) {
  for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
    (function(i) {
      el[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        callback(this, event);
      });
    })(i);
  }
  window.CP.exitedLoop(0);
}
```

As you can see, the second parameter is a `callback`.
That `callback` gets called when click is made on a certain element, and it gets called with two parameters here:

```
callback(this, event);
```

Getting back to your code, then, we can see that event should be the second parameter of your callback:

```
function dismissModal() {
  bindEvents(_dismiss, function(that, event) {
    hideModal(event);
  });
}
```

This way, it is defined (as the callback argument) and assigned by the `bindEvents` when an element is clicked.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: World-class!! Thanks a lot for the thorough insight and your solution.